# Different types of data in different classes

Tags: java, inheritance, data-structures, types

```
public class Node
{
    Node next, child;
    String data;

    Node()
    {
        this(null);
    }

    Node(String s)
    {
        data = s;
        next = child = null;
    }

    Node get(int n)
    {
        Node x = this;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
            x = x.next;
        return x;
    }

    int length()
    {
        int l;
        Node x = this;
        for(l=0; x!=null; l++)
            x = x.next;
        return l;
    }

    void concat(Node b)
    {
        Node a = this.get(this.length() - 1);
        a.next = b;
    }

    void traverse()
    {
        Node x = this;
        while(x!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(x.data);
            x = x.next;
        }
    }
}

class IntegerNode extends Node
{
    int data;

    IntegerNode(int x)
    {
        super();
        data = x;
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can have different types of `data` in the two classes so that I can use the `IntegerNode` class with numbers and the `Node` class with Strings?

Example:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        IntegerNode x = new IntegerNode(9);
        IntegerNode y = new IntegerNode(10);
        x.concat(y);
        x.concat(new Node("End"));
        x.traverse();
    }
}
```

Right now, this is the output I'm getting:
`null`
`null`
`End`

Any explanation would help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *default* way would be to use **[generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html)**.

Like:

```
public class Node <T> {
  private final T data;

  public Node(T data) { this.data = data; }
```

to then use like:

```
Node<Integer> intNode = new Node<>(5);
Node<String> stringNode = new Node<>("five");
```

Please note: the *above* is how you solve such problems in Java. Using inheritance here would a rather wrong approach. Unless you would *really* find a good reason to be able to `concat()` nodes with *different* data. As my solution fully "separates" a `Node<Integer>` form a `Node<String>`. And yes, that means that users could create `Node<Whatever>` objects at any time.

Thus: if you really want **only** Integer and String data nodes - then you would actually do the following:

- make the base Node class hold data as `Object`
- make the base class abstract
- create two specific subclasses for Integer/String, as outlined in the other answer

But the question would be: what happens when you decide next week that you want Float and Double, too. And maybe Dates? Then you would have to create new subclasses each time. Leading to a lot of duplicated code.

So the *real* answer here: really *think* your requirements through. Understand what is exactly that you want to build. And then see which path you should take.

Comment: I agree that this is a better approach but wouldn't this let user choose data types beyond integer and string ?

Comment: Yes Indeed it would, but you could provide concrete implementations for integer and string, if those are the only 2 that you want used. By the way the proper name for *generics* is `parameterized types`.

Comment: Thank you. Generics was what I was looking for

Comment: @Nerzid That's what I wanted: the user should be able to use any data type